# How to do multiple find one and update on multiple collections efficiently / at high performance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, e-commerce

I am using mongodb and nodejs, my use case is like this,

When a user purchase a product with his score stored in his user document, I will need to update the product document to decrease its stock, then need to decrease the score of the user in the user document, then need to create a transaction record. Here three collections are involved, should I do 3 times findOne and Save() in nested promise structure?

Or there is any other more efficient way to do it?

I am currently using mongoese, should I switch to mongodb official client instead?

```
Collection1.findOne( doc1 => {
    doc1.save().then({

        Collection2.findOne( doc2 => {
            doc1.save().then({

                Collection3.findOne( doc3 => {
                    doc1.save().then({

                    })
                })

            })
        })

    })
})
```

Comment: if you're using MongoDB version 4+ you could consider using transactions (just a note, transactions are only available in a replica set environment)

Comment: Thanks @omarwaleed but currently I need yo stick to mongodb3.4

Answer (score 3):

As in @Raj Kumar's answer, you should use an async function but I would like to add to that the use of `Promise.all` instead of awaiting each request by itself. The final code would be

```
async function purchase() {
  try {
    let promise1 = Collection1.findOneAndUpdate(
        condition,
        update
    );

    let promise2 = Collection2.findOneAndUpdate(
        condition,
        update
    );

    let promie3 = Collection3.findOneAndUpdate(
        condition,
        update
    );
    let result = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])

  } catch(err) {
      // handle error in any promise
  }
}
```

Comment: correct! waiting for one operation to happen is not required if you are just doing write operation or result of one operation is dependent on other. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

use findOneAndUpdate instead. It will help li'l bit. See the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

And try to avoid callbacks, instead use async await as mongoose will return a promise in any db operation.

```
async function purchase() {
    try {
        let doc1 = await Collection1.findOneAndUpdate(
            condition,
            updatedDoc
        );

        let doc2 = await Collection2.findOneAndUpdate(
            condition,
            updatedDoc
        );

        let doc3 = await Collection3.findOneAndUpdate(
            condition,
            updatedDoc
        );
    } catch(err) {
        //
    }
}
```